# Can GASToken be used in DEXs?

Tags: gas, decentralized-exchange

Can GASTokens be used in decentralized exchanges to reduce the GAS used in transactions?

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what is a GAS token, but it doesn't make much difference. You cannot pay for transactions with tokens - only by gas which in turn uses Ether. So, at least in a simple DEX (decentralized exchange) where you simply swap assets, you can't pay transactions with tokens.

If the DEX uses state channels or Plasma or something similar for longer trading, then in theory it may be possible to use tokens for some valuation of transactions - but the starting and ending transactions would still require regular gas at least.

Answer (score 1):

You are wrong. :)

Gastoken takes advantage of Ethereum's native gas refund mechanism, so while it cannot fully pay for a transaction, it can definitely be used to lower the costs of transacting.

Comment: It seems that you reply to above answer. Use comment for that.